How can I squash some git commits after I've done a merge (but before it's been pushed)
I just went through a lengthy merge conflict and noticed that I have a bunch of commits from my working tree that should have been squashed before I did the merge. I have not pushed the merge yet but I would like to avoid having to re-do the merge after checking out a new branch and doing the squash.
Is there a way that I can do something similar to cherry-picking the merge commit but changing the relevant parent of the merge?

you could probably perform a git rebase --interactive that would squash the commits that have contributed to your merge, git rebase --interactive HEAD^2~n, where n is the number of commits you want to edit/squash. However, this will prompt you to resolve the same conflicts commit by commit, which is not what you were looking for.

TL;DR
You can use git checkout <commit-or-branch> . to checkout the contents of the commit with the resolved conflicts into your current sandbox in the middle of redoing the merge.
Assumptions

I'm going to assume you've merged branch feature into main and you want to squash some commits in feature, and then redo the merge.

You don't have any work that's not committed yet in this sandbox, so it's OK to do a hard reset in step 3 below.


Detailed recipe
The solution I would use is:

Save the current merge with its resolved conflicts by creating a new branch:
git branch saved-merge main


Rebase your feature branch interactively and squash as needed:
git checkout feature
git rebase --interactive <ref-to-parent-of-feature-branch>


Undo the original merge:
git checkout main
git reset --hard HEAD^  # or where main was before the merge


Redo the merge, but instead of resolving the conflicts, checkout the contents of the saved merge:
git merge feature
git checkout saved-merge .
git commit



The key is this git checkout saved-merge .: by giving . as the path, it checks out the full contents of the head commit on saved-merge into your sandbox, overwriting all the files with their conflict markers with the versions you resolved the first time around.
Note you have to run this command at the root of your sandbox, so that . means the whole file tree, or use :/ or ':(top)' instead of  ., as suggested by @phd (thank you for that!).

git checkout saved-merge :/ or git checkout saved-merge :(top) ; see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec

My 15 minutes of fame! :-)))

Doh! Sorry about that. Fixed.

There is a general solution for this which enables you to change commits in the past without having to redo merges that happened afterwards, which is especially useful if there were conflicts in any of the merges. In your particular case it appears the merge is at the tip of your branch, so joanis' solution should work. If you have more commits you'd like to retain after that merge, or if you don't wish to change any historical meta data in commits you aren't touching, try this method. It involves using a combination of git replace and git-filter-repo (which must be installed separately). The algorithm is:

Checkout the most recent commit you wish to rewrite, and use some form of reset or interactive rebase to rewrite the commits the way you want them.
Use git replace to replace the old commit with the new one.
Use git-filter-repo to make the replacement permanent.

Once you have git-filter-repo installed, you can try this working example:
#!/bin/bash

git init
git branch -m main # in case it defaults to something else
echo A > A.txt && git add . && git commit -m "A"
echo B > B.txt && git add . && git commit -m "B"

git switch -c feature
echo C > C.txt && git add . && git commit -m "C"
echo D > D.txt && git add . && git commit -m "D squash me into C?"
echo E > E.txt && git add . && git commit -m "E squash me into C?"

git switch main
echo X > X.txt && git add . && git commit -m "X"
echo Y > Y.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Y"

# merge in feature
git merge feature -m "Merge feature into main"
git log --graph --oneline

# squash the 3 commits on feature:
git switch --detach feature
git reset --soft HEAD~3
git commit -m "Squash of C,D,E"

# Replace the previous feature branch with the squashed commit
git replace main^2 @
git log main --graph --oneline
git switch main

# make the replace permanent
git filter-repo --replace-refs update-or-add --force
git log main --graph --oneline

Here's what the output of each of the above git log commands look like:
### Initial graph
*   3ea45ba (HEAD -> main) Merge feature into main
|\
| * 6408cf1 (feature) E squash me into C?
| * dbee360 D squash me into C?
| * 4df7d83 C
* | afb7249 Y
* | 2034ce1 X
|/
* 47c2f1c B
* 5ee4cc9 A

### After squash and git replace
*   3ea45ba (main) Merge feature into main
|\
| * 6408cf1 (replaced, feature) Squash of C,D,E
* | afb7249 Y
* | 2034ce1 X
|/
* 47c2f1c B
* 5ee4cc9 A

### After replace made permanent
*   214221d (HEAD -> main) Merge feature into main
|\
| * 0fbc09a (feature) Squash of C,D,E
* | afb7249 Y
* | 2034ce1 X
|/
* 47c2f1c B
* 5ee4cc9 A



Is there a way that I can do something similar to cherry-picking the merge commit but changing the relevant parent of the merge?

Yes, the "similar to cherry-picking" operation is git diff ... | git apply -.
Rebase has a --rebase-merges option that you can make use of here. While the rebase operation will at the end attempt to create a new merge commit that then will have conflicts, since you already have resolved those in the original merge you can reuse that result via git diff ... | git apply -.

Assuming your worktree does not contain extra files (log files etc) that you do not want to have committed. All git commands run from top directory. Screenshots from gitk --all.

So assuming your current starting point looks like the following where you want to squash f2a and f2b into a single f2 commit, and the same for f4a and f4b.

Then the steps are
git checkout feature
git tag conflicts-already-resolved     # Save reference
git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges start

which then brings up the following rebase todo list:
label onto

# Branch main
reset onto
pick b87fec1 m4
pick c72850d m5
pick 7ffc0c3 m6
label main

reset onto
pick 7b41ef7 f1
pick 074b593 f2a
pick 188a82b f2b
pick c6734b2 f3
pick f8f991a f4a
pick 00f2488 f4b
pick 0c7b9a7 f5
merge -C 53a3444 main # Merge branch 'main' into feature

which you then change to
label onto

# Branch main
reset onto
pick b87fec1 m4
pick c72850d m5
pick 7ffc0c3 m6
label main

reset onto
pick 7b41ef7 f1
pick 074b593 f2a
squash 188a82b f2b
pick c6734b2 f3
pick f8f991a f4a
squash 00f2488 f4b
pick 0c7b9a7 f5
merge -C 53a3444 main # Merge branch 'main' into feature

and then amend the squashed commit messages when prompted. Eventually the last merge operation will fail due to conflicts1. But you have already resolved those so we can reuse that result. Git will have the files with conflicts marked as modified with embedded conflict marker text. We do not care about those now2, so discard those with
git checkout .

Now to reuse the work you originally did to resolve merge conflicts, you simply tell git "make my current worktree identical to the content of the conflicts-already-resolved commit" by piping the output from git diff into git apply:
git diff -R conflicts-already-resolved | git apply -
git add .
git commit                     # Complete the merge conflict
git rebase --continue
git diff feature conflicts-already-resolved    # Should show no difference

This will give you

which is what you wanted. The conflicts-already-resolved tag is no longer needed and can be deleted
git tag -d conflicts-already-resolved

giving you the cleaner result

Now after the rebase is finished it is time to re-run all your git test tests
git test run -t mytest1 start..feature
git test run -t mytest2 start..feature
git test run -t mytest3 start..feature
git test run -t mytest4 start..feature
...


1
When you say you have had a lengthy merge conflict I suspect that is because you are not using a proper full 3-way merge tool to resolve those. I strongly recommend using KDiff3. Full 3-way merge tools are one of those things that once you have started using you never want to go back to not using.
2
In fact you should never care about those since you always should be using a proper full 3-way merge tool.
